# Mongoid has_many association and factorygirl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot

I am using mongoid for the first time and I am having a problem creating a has_many association in a factory for my specs.

The scenario is this:

I have the a group class:

```
class Group
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, :type => String
end
```

And I have an exercise class.  An exercise can belong to many groups.  The exercise class is currently defined like this:

```
class Exercise
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, :type => String
  field :description, :type => String

  has_many :groups

  validates_presence_of :name, :description
end
```

I want to use factorygirl to create instances for specs.  I am struggling with how to do this.

Currently my exercise factory looks like this;

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :exercise do
    name "Preacher curls"
    description "Do something"

    after(:build) do |exercise|
      exercise.groups << FactoryGirl.build(:group)
    end
  end
end
```

This causes the following error:

> ```
>  NoMethodError:
>    undefined method `=' for #<Group _id: 4fbc6f5a26a3181742000004, _type: nil, name: "Arms">
> ```

How can I create the exercise factory correctly to add the group_ids?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add

```
belongs_to :exercise
```

into your Group class

It should look like this:

```
class Group
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, :type => String
  belongs_to :exercise
end
```